# Calling external api in Nginx location section

Tags: nginx

I am trying to resolve proxy_pass value dynamically (through web api) in nginx.

I need something like below;
Example taken from: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

```
location /proxy-pass-uri {
    set $urlToProxy = CallWebAPI("http://localhost:8081/resolver?url=" + $url);
    proxy_pass $urlToProxy;         
}
```

So, my question is that, is it possible to make HTTP request or to write method such as CallWebAPI?

I know it might be a bad practice, but the website I am dealing with has thousands of  web urls, which are mapped as key-value pairs, and 90% of them does not obey any specific regex rules. So I have content mapped database, and I need to fetch incoming url with content dynamically.

I am trying to use a very light web service to look up URLs from redis, and return proxy url.

Would this be a valid scenario, or is there any other built in solution in nginx like this?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this can be done with "pure" nginx, but this definitely can be done with [openresty](https://github.com/openresty/openresty) or [ngx_http_lua_module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) with the help of [ngx.location.capture](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture) method. For example:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
location ~/proxy-pass-uri(/.*)$ {
    set $url $1;
    set $proxy "";
    access_by_lua_block {
       res = ngx.location.capture("http://localhost:8081/resolver?url=" .. ngx.var.url)
       ngx.var.proxy = res.body
    }
    proxy_pass $proxy$url;
}
```

There is also an [ngx_http_js_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html) ([documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/index.html), [GitHub](https://github.com/nginx/njs)) which have an ability to do subrequests ([example](https://www.nginx.com/blog/batching-api-requests-nginx-plus-javascript-module/)), but I never used it and cannot tell if it can be used this way.

**Important update**

After almost a three years since this answer was written, it comes that I needed the similar functionality myself, and it turns out that the above answer is completely broken and unworkable. You can't do a subrequest via `ngx.location.capture` to anything else but to some other nginx location. So the correct (checked and confirmed to be workable) example for the above question is

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
location /resolver {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
location ~ ^/proxy-pass-uri(/.*)$ {
    set $url $1;
    set $proxy "";
    access_by_lua_block {
        res = ngx.location.capture("/resolver?url=" .. ngx.var.url)
        if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
            ngx.var.proxy = res.body
        else
            ngx.exit(res.status)
        end
    }
    proxy_pass $proxy$url$is_args$args;
}
```

The above example assumes that the proxy resolution service is really expecting request in a `/resolver?url=<uri>` form. The `location /resolver { ... }` while being internal behaves like any other prefix location, so if the `/resolver` prefix for that location cannot be used for some reason, the same can be written as

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
location /get_proxy {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/resolver;
}
location ~ ^/proxy-pass-uri(/.*)$ {
    set $url $1;
    set $proxy "";
    access_by_lua_block {
        res = ngx.location.capture("/get_proxy?url=" .. ngx.var.url)
        if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
            ngx.var.proxy = res.body
        else
            ngx.exit(res.status)
        end
    }
    proxy_pass $proxy$url$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript one looks very promising, I will check this and let you know, thanks!