# Dynamic string redirection, all in the NGINX script

Tags: nginx

Can I use Lua or similar module (but no external software) to get string from a proxy processor and use it into another proxy?

Real example of ordinary proxy:

```
  location /_test/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
```

Now  suppose that GET `http://localhost:3000/?uri=$uri` returns one text line, an URL, for example `https://youtube.com`. Of course, it is dynamic, changes with time or `$uri` used... Imaginary exemple of my need:

```
  location /_test/ {
    set redir_string = http://localhost:3000/?uri=$uri  #Lua or other magic to set
    # the value of redir_string is a new URL
    proxy_pass $redir_string;
  }
```

---

### NOTES

This **is not a duplicate**, we need complete and **simple NGINX location script**, and the [question/answer 53799389](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799389/calling-external-api-in-nginx-location-section) is not a solution without it (is impossible to **reuse or adapt**).

Comment: Sure. Use [`ngx.location.capture`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture). Do you need a full working example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling external api in Nginx location section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799389/calling-external-api-in-nginx-location-section)

Comment: Hi @IvanShatsky, seems the solution (!). I have no working example because my `localhost:3000`, that returns the URL text on GET response,  is http://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/api.html#stored-procedures

Comment: Turns out I give you a link to the unworkable answer once upon a time. My apologies. I knew it for a couple of time, and today I fix it (at last). Today is exactly a five years since I registered on SO. I'm sort of reviewing my old answers and some of them really makes me cry :)

Comment: Hi @IvanShatsky, happy SO_birthday!  Don't cry, I'm an old man, so, I can tell you: life is short, and happy are those who find time to correct the mistakes of the past!

Comment: PS: seems that a good solution is to use NGINX's Lua module, https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/