# Nginx : dispatch request to multi endpoints

Tags: nginx, lua

My goal is to delete a file from another servers for that reason i need to dispatch the request into these endpoints at the same time.

```nginx
location / {
   
   set_by_lua_block $url_format {
   .. block lua for string manipulation and constructing which return as example '/images/test.png'
   }
   
  set $cdn1 "http://server1.com";
  set $cdn2 "http://server2.com";
   
  proxy_set_header Host main-server.com;
  proxy_pass $cdn1$url_format;
  proxy_pass $cdn2$url_format;
}
```

When executing, I get the error :

```
"proxy_pass" directive is duplicate
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Try [`ngx.location.capture`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture) (or maybe [`ngx.location.capture_multi`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture_multi)). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53804483/7121513) answer for an example.

Comment: thank you @IvanShatsky for your help, i've tried ur suggestion but nothing new still cannot produce it

Comment: @algotourist you can't do multiple `proxy_pass`es in one locaton, you should split it

Comment: @user973254 is there a way, to dispatch it by spliting, but let's say i've more than two endpoints what did suggestion for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was suggesting:

```
location / {
    set_by_lua_block $url_format {
        -- block lua for string manipulation and constructing which return as example '/images/test.png'
    }
    # variables should be pre-initialized
    set $cdn '';
    set $url '';
    content_by_lua_block {
        local cdns = { "http://server1.com", "http://server2.com" }
        local reqs = {}
        for _, cdn_name in ipairs(cdns) do
            table.insert(reqs, { "/dispatcher", { vars = { cdn = cdn_name, url = ngx.var.url_format } } })
        end
        local resps = { ngx.location.capture_multi(reqs) }
        -- analyze 'resps' table here, generate response (see ngx.say, ngx.exit functions)
    }
}

location /dispatcher {
    internal;
    resolver 8.8.8.8; # use any resolver that is able to resolve server1.com, server2.com etc.
    proxy_pass $cdn$url;
}
```

See [this](https://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) article for the decription why do you need a `resolver` directive here. Most likely you can move your code from the `set_by_lua_block` to the `content_by_lua_block` to slightly simplify the config. If you need some specific HTTP request method (e.g. `DELETE`) to be used, see [HTTP method constants](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#http-method-constants) documentation chapter.

Comment: appreciate it man, it does indeed work

Comment: Hi Ivan, i've a question about how to return a response through `content_by_lua_block` into an if condition of `nginx`, let's take an example :  
location  / {
   if ($request_method = 'DELETE') {
       content_by_lua_block {
             ...               
            ngx.say(json.encode(json.decode(resp.body)));
            return ngx.exit(statusCode);
        }
   }
}

Comment: @algotourist Do not even try to use nginx `if` blocks for the tasks like that. That directive is a very special one, it doesn't work in a way like it works in programming languages. It makes some kind of "virtual" location instead. Made all the checks inside the lua code. To limit allowed HTTP methods to some subset see the [`limit_except`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except) directive.

Comment: thanks for your pertinent remark, btw let's give an image about my location rule which tries to handle two requests method `Get` and `Delete`, when u try to retrieve an image from the server i need at first to check if already exist if it does i'll serve it directly without going through the `Application`, to make that happen i added an `alias /var/dev/static/cache/` then `try_files $url_format/index.php;`.Awesome, let's get back to our main point, after a bit of digging though of how to put those `alias and try_files` into a condition if not `delete` method, but i'm till stuck in it.